# Flexdashboard two or more dimensions Layout

Tags: r, layout, flexdashboard

I have a table with 5 columns, all are integers, and all of them correspond to the month of January 2023, which has 31 days, therefore 31 rows. Each table is a time series.

I'm putting those tables into a dashboard. When I put orientation rows, it gives me a 5 x 1 array. When I put orientation columns, it gives me a 1 x 5 array. So much blank space left because I'm not able to distribute the tables 2 x 3.

Is there any way I can do 2 x 3 or 3 x 2 and the plots get adjusted to the panels?

[Image Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BiFT9X7xihnRaIaTBwmbCIpYFqin-2o8/view?usp=sharing)

Is there any way to organize this better? (The code seems unorganized because I was not able to delete the chunk lines)

Here's the code and data set.

[Code and Dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WrxhMMiAMwImgW4g4hUPDaSTl36-maz8?usp=sharing)